# Javascript TypeError is undefined?

Tags: javascript, money.js

I'm using `money.js` and use it for currency conversion. My code as follows.

```
var ctryCode;
var currencyCode;
var reponse_url = 'http://xxx';

$.getJSON(reponse_url, function(data) {
    ctryCode = data.countryCode;
    var url = 'assets/js/Common-Currency.json';

    $.getJSON(url, function(info) {
        currencyCode = info[ctryCode].code;

        fx.base = "USD";

        fx.settings = {
            from : "USD"
        };

        $.getJSON('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?xxx', function(data) {
            if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
            }
            else {
                var fxSetup = {
                    rates : data.rates,
                    base : data.base
                }
            }
        });

        var x = fx(1).to(currencyCode);
        alert( x + " " + currencyCode);
    });
});
```

This returns `TypeError: info[ctryCode] is undefined` `currencyCode = info[ctryCode].code;`. I cant find any wrong in my code. Why this happens?

Here is the sample response from `response_url`

```
{"country":"Sri Lanka","countryCode":"LK"}
```

My Common-Currency.json JSON file as follows. Get Currency code by using country code.

```
{
    "US": {
        "symbol": "$",
        "code": "USD"
    },
    "LK": {
        "symbol": "CA$",
        "code": "LKR
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't possibly help you without knowing what the `data` object you receive in response to your first request is, what the `info` object you receive in response to your second is, etc. But moreover: The way to find out what's wrong is to **use your debugger**. There's a fully-featured one built into your browser. Use it. You can then look at the values of things, step through the code, etc. Clearly, `info[ctryCode]` results in `undefined`. Only you can find out why.

Comment: @choz: There are no promises used above.

Comment: info object does not contain a property with the same value of ctryCode. You should show some more info about your data...

Comment: `url` needs to be absolute.

Comment: @MarcoS I have added my JSON file to question and error throws on `currencyCode = info[ctryCode].code;` line.

Comment: You should use a console.log to show `info` contents and `ctryCode` value,  just before that line, and try to understand why they are different from what you do expect...